# Cypher query: how to filter a MATCH based on a previous result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with a graph model that looks like the one below ([source](https://neo4j.com/graphgists/international-flights-database/)).
[image]

I want to find all domestic flights for a particular country, that is flights that have both a `DESTINATION` and `SOURCE` flight in an airport that belongs to that country. This is the Cypher query I'm working on:

```
MATCH (cr:Country {name:'Italy'})<-[:EXIST]-(ct:City)<-[:IS_IN]-(ai:Airport)
WITH ai
MATCH (ai)-[:DESTINATION|:SOURCE]-(f:Flight)-[:OF]-(ar:Airline)
WITH ar as airline, count(distinct(f)) as flights
ORDER BY flights DESC
RETURN airline.name, flights
LIMIT 10
```

The problem with the above query is that it will also return flights with a `DESTINATION` or `SOURCE` that is not in `Italy`. Can you help me to rephrase the query to get the correct results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is allowing the SOURCE **OR** the DESTINATION to be in Italy. You want both of them to be in Italy.
One option is something like:

```
MATCH (:Country {name:'Italy'})<-[:EXIST]-(:City)<-[:IS_IN]-(:Airport)-[:SOURCE]-(f:Flight)-[:DESTINATION]-(:Airport)-[:IS_IN]->(:City)-[:EXIST]->(:Country {name:'Italy'})
WITH distinct(f) as flights
MATCH (flights)-[:OF]-(ar:Airline)
WITH ar as airline, count(flights) as flights
ORDER BY flights DESC
RETURN airline.name, flights
LIMIT 10
```